# How to find projects in gihub which use a certain gem

Tags: github

How to find projects in github which use a certain gem. (e.g. I would like to find projects using activeresource).

https://rubygems.org/gems/activeresource

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple code search on GitHub like:

https://github.com/search?l=Ruby&q=gem+activeresource+language%3ARuby+language%3ARuby&ref=advsearch&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93

You can quickly see all the projects including a `Gemfile` result (which includes a `gem "activeresource"` declaration in it).